# How to arrange for code to run at compile time in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a possibility to execute some code during compile time?

For example, I would like to check if the requested methods of a dynamic object exist in the parameter-type of a generic class.

```
 // This code has no actual purpose, just as an example
 public class Sample<T>
 {
     public Sample<T>(T instance)
     {
         foo = Value = instance;
         /* adding some extra code(e.g. logging) to the methods of T, by
inserting a "M" in front of the method names of T */
     }

     public T Value { get; }
     public dynamic foo { get; }
 }
```

How it would/could be used

```
var foo = new Sample<string>("hey");
foo.MSubstring(0,0);
```

Now I want to know if there's a possibility to execute code at compile time, e.g., to throw an exception before runtime that `foo.MgetSize()` doesn't exist in T.

(This question is only about how to execute code at compile time, and this sample isn't a real problem.)

I don't have a plan how to do that. Maybe using those `#if`- things?

Comment: One of those "`#if` things" is called a [Preprocessor Directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx).

Comment: Is this an XY problem?

Comment: Static typing exists to provide pretty much this feature: a compile time error at a type mismatch. By choosing to use dynamic typing at that point, you are explicitly opting out of this exact feature. If this is just an example and not the real problem you're trying to solve, perhaps you should describe that instead.

Comment: Well I could get through reflection all method names and would like to check if they're matching my "M"-'pattern'

Comment: @Tom it is not supposed to be such an XY problem. I've got some ideas if there would exist such a feature... (Especially because I'm recently experimenting with combining System.Reflection and dynamic objects with dynamicly generated code... )

Comment: Why you want to do that then? Please explain it in detail, i'm sure we might then find a solution which is working for you.

Comment: in your example, Sample itself is not a dynamic, so it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to execute code at build time. After all, the tools that build your program are, themselves, code.

What you're asking is how to customize that build process and execute some additional logic during it. How you would do this depends on the actual tools you're using - for example, for Visual Studio and the MSBuild system, you can refer to the [MSDN documentation on custom build steps and build events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e85wte0k.aspx).

What your custom build tool would be like depends on what part of the process it will fire up in. If it works with source code, it needs to be able to parse C# source code (and probably Visual Studio project files as well). If it works by verifying the emitted assembly (the binary that's produced at the end of the typical build process), it could simply use reflection to detect the errors you want. I'd say the latter is more convenient.

Comment: Yes, a "custom build step" is needed for this; there's nothing built into the C# language.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, you can use [T4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit) for compile-time checking.

Another way is to use languages that support compile-time macros. For example, [Nemerle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemerle) or [Boo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_%28programming_language%29).

Maybe you can use [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform). But only in C# 6.

Comment: Please explain what T4 and Roslyn are.

Comment: @JørgenFogh T4 is a code-generation templating implementation. E.g. you can specify that you want to call a method 5 times, with different parameters, and that is inserted at compile time into your code. 


Roslyn is the static analyzer for .NET/C# and can be ("easily") extended to provide custom analyzers etc.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you could run some code that you just compiled in the "Post Build" step of Visual Studio.

You might be able to use a tool like Post#, to do what you want by creating attributes that do the checking you have in mind. See: https://www.postsharp.net/product/how-it-works

In other languages, like Jai, you can do this easily. See *"[Arbitrary compile-time code execution](https://sites.google.com/site/jailanguageprimer/)"*.

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *https://www.postsharp.net/customers*

Answer (score 0):

The scenario where a certain function might exist and might not exist is a little sketchy. It is better to include a *Convert* method in your interface and the object itself can tell you whether it implements the functionality, and return an object with the appropriate interface, or null if it does not.

Although, it *could* be done with preprocessor, I wouldn't recommend it. The scenario you are describing would mean that you are including one header that does define that method for the object, *or* one that does not. You don't get real dynamics. So in the header that does, use a

```
#define HASMETHOD
```

and in your executor use:

```
#ifdef HASMETHOD
   foo.MSubstring(0, 0);
#endif
```

But again, I *strongly* recommend against this. Use a method, you call at runtime to determine, that returns the interface to call.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot execute code at compile time by definition. You can however execute code at load time (actually before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced) using static constructors:

[link to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: What definition is that? Certainly you can have a compiler that executes arbitrary code as part of compilation.

Comment: I mean the definition of the word 'compile'. The way I understand it is that at compile time code is compiled, not executed.

Comment: C++ compilers routinely "execute code" at compile time (for various meanings of the term, anything from TMP to explicitly with `constexpr`). It is true, though, that C# compilers don't.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield: That's true, but there are many "code weaver" tools made to operate on .NET assemblies at build time (not "compile time" per se), for example to implement aspect-oriented programming.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I didn't mean to imply otherwise. Just pointing out that just because a C++ compiler can do it doesn't automatically mean C# compilers can. :)

Comment: Just to add something interesting, XNA (C#) has the concept of Content Pipelines. These are Projects that are included in the solution that process data (models/textures) into whatever custom format you like at compile time. This can be useful for doing things like adding FFT data to audio or "baking" textures/shadows, content that will never change and does not need to be re-calculated.

Comment: Re *"You cannot execute code at compile time by definition"*: You can. That is very fundamental to how [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) works, e.g. so-called [defining words](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/11-forth-compiler-defining-words/) (they have (different) behavior at runtime and at compile time). They execute both at runtime and at compile time. The compiler is also extendable.